# Non const anonymous reference in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, reference, anonymous

I've looked quiet some time but I find it hard to find an answer to this problem* which I think someone with more c++ experience finds pretty obvious.

Consider this class:

```
class A {
    public:
        A( const char * name ){}
};

class X {
    public:
        X( A const&a ) {}
};

class Y {
    public:
        Y( A &a ) {}
};
```

And this code:

```
A a( "1" );
X x1( a ); // Works

X x2( A( "2" ) ); // Works

Y y3( A( "3" ) ); // Error!
```

So why can I pass an object by non-const reference to an Constructor but not an anonymous one?

And is there another way to write something like this to have these objects constructed on the heap**?

```
Car car( Person( "Mike" ), Person( "Sandra" ) );
```

Thanks in advance!

---

*) Hard because searching for "const anonymous reference constructor" yields many but mostly unrelated answers.
**) I'm doing embedded stuff...

Comment: _So why can I pass an object by non-const reference to an Constructor but not an anonymous one?_ On that contrary. Temporary **can** bind to a `const` reference, but **can't** bind to a non-`const` reference. Your 2nd/3rd examples demonstrates just that.

Comment: Temporary cannot bind to non-const reference.

Comment: *"const temporary reference constructor"* gives better results.